# Unable to put padding between border and content of a label

Tags: html, css

I have created labels as buttons for the radio buttons. Unable to find out why I cant put a padding between the border on the background color content.

Do I need to restructure the radio/label, or am I missing something that I can't put padding on the checked/hover labels?

```css
.product-form__input input[type="radio"] + .color-swatch {
  border: 3px solid #f4f5ff;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
}

.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:checked + .color-swatch,
.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:hover + .color-swatch {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.product-form__input input[type=radio]+label {
    border-radius: 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="js product-form__input">
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" name="Color" value="BLACK">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" style="background-color: #ff0000"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" name="Color" value="GREY" checked="">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" style="background-color: #a1a1a1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Background color will also color any padding. Are you trying to get a white circle between the gray and the black border of the second label?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth correct thats my goal, is to have white space between the content and border

Answer (score 0):

background-color will color any padding as well.

Instead, you can use a background-image which is a radial gradient, the middle bit being the gray and the outer bit white:

```css
.product-form__input input[type="radio"]+.color-swatch {
  border: 3px solid #f4f5ff;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
}

.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:checked+.color-swatch,
.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:hover+.color-swatch {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.product-form__input input[type=radio]+label {
  border-radius: 4rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="js product-form__input">
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" name="Color" value="BLACK">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" style="background-color: #ff0000"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" name="Color" value="GREY" checked="">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" style="background-image: radial-gradient(#a1a1a1 0 50%, white 20% 100%);"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have space between background color and border of an element.

Maybe you can use `:after` to draw a larger circle and get some spacing.

```css
.product-form__input input[type="radio"] + .color-swatch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:not(:hover):not(:checked) + label:after {
  border-color: #f4f5ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="js product-form__input">
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" name="Color" value="BLACK">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" style="background-color: #ff0000"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" name="Color" value="GREY" checked="">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" style="background-color: #a1a1a1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to answer my own question after more research, I used outline and offset-outline to solve the issue.

```css
.product-form__input input[type="radio"] + .color-swatch {
  outline-offset: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:checked + .color-swatch,
.product-form__input input[type="radio"]:hover + .color-swatch {
  outline: 2px solid #000000;
}

.product-form__input input[type=radio]+label {
    border-radius: 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="js product-form__input">
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" name="Color" value="BLACK">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-0" style="background-color: #ff0000"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" name="Color" value="GREY" checked="">
  <label class="color-swatch" for="template--14332506603656__main-Color-1" style="background-color: #a1a1a1"></label>
</div>
```